# clicking on an style="display: block;" in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

i am trying to click on an element for which style is **style="display: block;"** but not able to to do so.

below is the `html` code

```
<div class="fl f18 dtoggler pointer underline some-padding new_data_entry" data-div-id="eBWJcg" data-div-ref="new_Passport_form.eBWJcg">+ Add Passport</div>
<div class="clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable" style="display: none;">
```

`Selenium` code:

```
driver.get("idfystaging.com/users/sign_in"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("user[login]")).sendKeys("rustam1‌​@yopmail.com"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("user[password]")).sendKeys("Pass‌​word123"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();     
driver.switchTo().frame("upload_iframe_1");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESC‌​APE); 
JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('qEgULQ').st‌​yle.display='block';‌​");click();
```

Error log:

```
Cannot read property 'style' of null.
```

Comment: Can we have the Selenium code?

Comment: What do you mean by *not able to to do so*? what is the problem?

Comment: @kyle i am getting error that Cannot read property 'style' of null.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to apply `Javascript` to element with `id="qEgULq"` while you need element with `class="qEgULq"`:

Just replace

```
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('qEgULQ').st‌​yle.display='block';‌​");
```

with

```
executor.executeScript("document.querySelector('div.clear.new_Passport_form.qEgULQ.some-margin.togglable').st‌​yle.display='block';‌​");
```

Also note that your `click();` from provided piece of code doesn't bound to element

**Update**

If some of class names are generated dynamically or assigned just on some events, you can avoid using class names as locator:

```
WebElement targetDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='+ Add Passport']/following-sibling::div"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].st‌​yle.display='block';‌​", targetDiv);
```

Comment: on which of those lines?

Comment: executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('div.clear.new_Passport_form.qEgULQ.some-margin.togglable').st‌​yle.display='block';");

Comment: update: on clicking on +Add Passport style changes from style = "display: none;" to style="display: block;"

Comment: There is no `document.getElementsByClassName()` in my code. Just replace it with `document.querySelector()`

Comment: Could you re-write this line manually? There might be hidden characters when you make copy/paste