# getText() and getFirstSelectedOption().getText() not giving the expected text

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to display all the options of a drop down and then select one option

```
public class Toolsqa_SelectMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/selectmenu/");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='speed']"));
        Select s = new Select(e);
        System.out.println("First selected item : " + s.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());

        List<WebElement> options = s.getOptions(); 

        for(WebElement w : options)     
        {
            System.out.println(" Items in drop down : " + w.getText());
        }

        s.selectByVisibleText("Faster");
    }

}
```

I am getting

```
First selected item : 
 Items in drop down : 
 Items in drop down : 
 Items in drop down : 
 Items in drop down : 
 Items in drop down : 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.13 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.43.181', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Expected:

```
First selected item : Medium
 Items in drop down : Slower
 Items in drop down : Slow
 Items in drop down : Medium
 Items in drop down : Fast
 Items in drop down : Faster
```

Comment: The element that you're trying to access has a `display:none` attribute. That is why you're seeing an `ElementNotVisibleException` exception. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42526630/1728790) and change `display` attribute to `block` and then run the code.

Comment: Or add a click method after this step ` WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='speed']")); ` and then

Comment: Thanks for the solution...

Comment: Is is working now?

Comment: no i am trying to paste the details but getting errors  WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='speed']"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].st‌​yle.display='block';‌​", e);

Comment: But got error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.63 seconds